# How to automatically change an attribute value after certain time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently creating an auction app and I am having a hard time figuring out how to change a value in the auction at a certain time.  This is the model for the auction class

```
#  id                 :bigint           not null, primary key
#  active             :integer          default(1)
#  auction_end_time   :datetime
#  auction_start_time :datetime
#  category           :string
#  current_price      :float
#  description        :text
#  highest_bid        :float
#  highest_bidder     :string
#  name               :string
#  seller             :string
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#  user_id            :bigint
```

When auction_end_time passes the current Time (Time.new.utc) I want to change the 'active' attribute to the value of '0' for false.  'active' is restricted to the values of 0 and 1 for true and false.

Comment: You need to use cron job to periodically check records for which time has passed and mark them. You can use whenever gem.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `active` has only two states – `true` and `false` and when that state depends only on if `auction_end_time` has already passed then you do not need that column at all.

To find all `active` auction you can use a scope like this:

```
scope :active, -> { where('auction_end_time > ?', Time.new.utc)
```

and to query if an auction is still `active` you can use a method like this:

```
def active?
  auction_end_time > Time.new.utc
end
```

Other approaches – like CRON jobs or background worker – will not be that reliable because they might run a few seconds too late or not at all if the underlaying system is down.